# Vue: I have a component that needs to use click.native conditionally

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a dynamic component that is sometimes `router-link` and sometimes an `a` element.
I need to use `@click.native` when it's a router link and otherwise, I need it to just be `@click` without the native modifier or else it won't work on the `a` tag.
Is there a way to handle this?

```
 <component
    @click.native="hasPerms"
    :is="checkComponent"
  />

  checkComponent() {
    if (this.show) {
       return 'router-link'
    } else {
       return 'a'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would an `<a>` element not work with `@click` as opposed to `@click.native`? Just `$emit` the click upwards so you can listen to it without the `native` modifier.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the other way around.  `@click.native` won't work on an `a` tag.  I even get the Vue warning: `[Vue warn]: The .native modifier for v-on is only valid on components but it was used on <a>.`

Comment: No. I meant that you should use `@click="$emit('click', $event)"` on the tag element within the component. This will propagate it regardless of nativity and you can use `@click` without fear.

Answer (score 1):

conditionally is the keyword here, so you could simply use conditional rendering. Just add it two times (with and without click.native) with the v-if/v-else directive

```
<component v-if="this.show" @click.native="hasPerms" />
<component v-else @click="hasPerms"/>
```

Comment: thanks...there's a lot of nested html inside of there.  I would be turning 30 lines of code into 60 then though by duplicating all the inside code

Comment: then you should probably refactor the html into sub-components.