# Vue: using both click and click.native on a dynamic component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a dynamic component that is either an `a` element or a `router-link` .  I want to call the same function on them but the problem is that `click.native` is needed when the component is `router-link` and if it's an `a` , `click.native` does not work so I need `click`.  Is there a problem having both like below? It works when I try it but wanted to see if there is an issue with it or if there is a better way to handle this with out lots of changes to my component.

I can't really do a `v-if/else` here because I don't want to duplicate the inner content, which would be identical regardless of whether the parent is an `a` or `router-link`.

```
<component 
   :is="checkComp" 
   @click="doStuff"
   @click.native="doStuff"
>
    <div>Lots of nested content in here</div>
</component>

checkComp() {
   if (this.showRouter) {
      return 'router-link'
   else {
      return 'a'
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue: I have a component that needs to use click.native conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289122/vue-i-have-a-component-that-needs-to-use-click-native-conditionally)

Comment: furthermore if you plan on potentially upgrading to Vue3 at some point, you might want to work without `.native` modifier regardless, since [it has been removed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/v-on-native-modifier-removed.html#_2-x-syntax).